substr_replace() calls on a result string inside a nested loop causes replacements on replaced text
I'm working on a project that takes text files from a folder and searches the text of each file for specific keywords that correspond to image files that I'm trying to insert in the text as an html image tag using php.
I got it almost working; the correct images get inserted at the desired points, and text files that do not contain a keyword remain untouched, but the text files that have images inserted are doubled: one text file with added image and one original text file.
I have tried different approaches but either it doesn't work at all, or the text files with inserted images are duplicated.
Where lies the fault? Am I going at it the wrong way?
Here is my code:
$path = // array of .txt-filenames with plain tekst
$imagepath = // array of .jpg-filenames

foreach ($path as $file) {

    $haystack = file_get_contents("$file");

    foreach ($imagepath as $imagefile) {
        $needle = $imagefile;
        $position = strpos($haystack,$needle);

        if ($position !== false) {
            $output = substr_replace($haystack, "<img src='$imagefile'>", $position, 0);
        } else {
            $output = $haystack;
        }
        echo $output;
    }
}


You have two nested loops here. You loop over all your files, and then for each file, you loop over all your image paths. And then you do echo $output; for each one of those image paths. Of course that gets you more than one output for each file. The echo $output; should be placed after the inner foreach loop.

@C3roe is right

file_get_contents("$file"); can be written as file_get_contents($file);.

Thank you so much all off you this was part of the solution. I had tried already it, but due to my other mistakes it still didn't work and I got lost. Thanks for setting me straight here, so I could address the other issues with help from the other commenters.

If you have two images in $imagepath and the second one is not found by strpos then I believe $output = $haystack; will revert previous changes.
Here's a code snippet with more meaningful variables.
<?php
$textFiles = [];
$imageFileNames = [];

foreach ($textFiles as $file) {
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

    foreach ($imageFileNames as $imageFileName) {
        $position = strpos($fileContent, $imageFileName);

        if ($position !== false) {
            $fileContent = substr_replace($fileContent, "<img src='$imageFileName' />", $position, 0);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $fileContent);
    echo $fileContent; // if you want to debug
}

We could argue that we're rewriting $file even if $fileContent has not changed is useless but that's another story!

That did the trick. I'm so happy, thanks a lot for this! I added some more images to my folder and the all get placed at the correct position without generating duplicates anymore. I want to thank everyone for their friendly help and patience.

I'm not writing anything to the files by the way, I'm only outputting everything to the browser, with a little css.

ha ha not need to feel like a dunce! You're improving with every script you write so keep at it!

You are building the $output string inside of a nested loop, so every time your inner loop restarts and finds whitelisted image filenames (even ones already affected), another replacement is made.
I recommend avoiding this problem by avoiding the nested loop.  Build a regex pattern of all qualifying image names, then make all possible replacements in each iterated file.

If $path is an array of filepaths, then call it $paths.
If $imagepath is an array of image filenames, then call it $imageNames.

$piped = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $imageNames));
foreach ($paths as $file) {
    echo preg_replace(
             "#$piped#",
             '<img src="$0">$0',
             file_get_contents($file)
         );
    echo "\n---\n"; // create some visual separation between files
}


Thank you @mickmackusa for this different, and more concise, approach. The update to my original code by other users has caused it to work, so I'll separately try your solution as well later.
